# How to dereference hash references

Tags: perl, hash, dereference

UPDATE: Everything I know about referencing/dereferencing came from here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/perl-array-reference-examples/

I'm working with a library that (from the library documentation):

`Returns a reference to an array of hash references`

This conceptually makes sense to me (i'm not new to programming) but doesn't make sense functionally (i'm, apparently, very new to perl).

Here's some code:

```
my $Obj  = QA::STK::ModuleImUsing->new(arguments, to, new);
$Obj->createClient();
$Obj->sync( ['/tmp/files/...']);
my $result = $Obj->method_in_question(['/tmp/files/ff-latest.xml']);
```

So far so good. `$result` now holds the reference to an array.

So when I do this:

```
print "Result: @{ $result} \n";
```

I get:

```
Result: HASH(0x20d95b0)
```

Lovely! But I still need to dereference the hash. However, here's where things get weird (or maybe they've already gotten weird?).

```
my $hash_ref = @{ $result};
print Dump($hash_ref));
```

I get this:

```
$VAR1 = 1;
```

Which...isn't what I was expecting at all.

Are my expectations wrong or am I dereferencing things in the wrong way?

Comment: `my $hash_ref = @{ $result};` - I'm sorry, but what's that supposed to do? Assign an array to a scalar? ) Why don't you just Dump `$result` itself?

Comment: I *think* it's supposed to dereference the array referenced by $result. And since that should be a hash reference, I put it into a scalar. I don't know if that's wrong....

Comment: You don't need to deference an array - you need to get its first element (which is a reference to a hash). One possible approach is to use this notation: `my $hash_ref = $result->[0];`

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: do you only ever need the first hash reference in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `@$result` is an array then your LHS must be a list. Otherwise `$hashref` will be assigned the array size.

```
my ($hash_ref) = @{ $result};
print Dump($hash_ref));
```

Comment: This is great but can you explain what's happening? Just tested it. This works. But...why?

Comment: @Ramy, Array in scalar context returns its length. `my (...) =` forces the use of the list assignment operator which evaluates its arguments in list context. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129

Answer (score 3):

- We have a `%hash`.
- To this, we have a hash reference `$hashref = \%hash`
- This hashref is inside an array `@array = ($hashref)`
- We get an array reference: `$arrayref = \@array`

This is our result: `$result = $arrayref`. Not let's work backwards:

- `@result_array = @$result`
- `$result_hashref = $result_array[0]` or combined: `$result_hashref = $result->[0]`
- `%result_hash = %$result_hashref` or combined: `%result_hash = %{ $result->[0] }` (note that these make a copy)
- To get an element in the result hash, we can do

  - `$result_hash{$key}`
  - `$result_hashref->{$key}`
  - `$result->[0]{$key}`

Note that `$scalar = @{ $arrayref }` does not work as you expect, because an array (which `@{ … }` is) returns the *length* of the array in scalar context. To force list context in an assignment, put the left hand side into parens: `(…) = here_is_list_context` (where `…` is a list of zero or more lvalues).

Answer (score 2):

```
my $hash_ref = @{$result};
```

is the same as

```
my @array = @{$result};
my $hash_ref = @array;
```

This forces the array to be evaluated in scalar context by the assignment operator, which causes it to evaluate as the number of items in the array, or 1.